# Rules for a 5th Level Arcane Ballista?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, magic-items, equipment

Looking for rules on how to run a semi sentient Arcane Ballista that can be used as a monster and equipment. Any ideas where I can find rules for this or does someone have rules they can share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dungeon Magazine 155 published an [arcane ballista](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/mobile/display.aspx?page=Monster&id=1029). It's level 6, but easily adjustable to 5.

```
Arcane Ballista

Initiative +8 Senses Perception +5; low-light vision HP 57; Bloodied 28 AC 18; Fortitude 17, Reflex 18, Will 15 Immune charm, disease, fear, poison, sleep; Resist 5 to all damage Speed 6

Slam (standard, at-will, MBA)

+13 vs AC; 1d6+4 damage.

Lightning Shot (standard, at-will, RBA) Lightning

Ranged 20; +11 vs Reflex; 1d10+5 lightning damage.

Lightning Burst (standard, at-will) Lightning

Area burst 2 within 20; +9 vs Reflex; 1d10+5 lightning damage.

Alignment Unaligned Languages -Str 19 (+7) Dex 20 (+8) Wis 14 (+5) Con 15 (+5) Int 3 (-1) Cha 6 (+1)
```

While no rules are published for capturing this an turning to your side, I'd imagine following similar rules to beast taming would be fair game (just sub arcana checks for nature checks).